# Local source control

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, interpreter

I've written my own local *"source control"*. Rather than using a commit-based system, when you're ready to release a version, you can run a command which will create a `.zip` copy of your source code, and it's saved to a `versions` folder.

---

## How does it work?

Each *"project"* written with this has a specific file structure that looks like the below. A file structure like this *is required* in order for the source control to work.

```
/[Project Name]
    /source
        ...

    /versions
        ...

    /info
        changelog.txt
        readme.txt
```

There are also three commands that are used. `new`, `push`, and `changedir`. Each command argument is double colon, `::`, separated, and look something like the following:

- `new::[project Name]::[project info]` - Create a new project.
- `push::[version name]::[version info]` - Push a new version to the `versions` folder as a `.zip` file.
- `changedir::[directory]` - Change to a new directory.

---

## Concerns

There are a few things I'm concerned about here.

- Have I designed this in a clear intuitive way? The current design right now feels clunky and hard to use.
- Am I over-documenting things? While I love documentation, if this is too much, tips on documentation would be appreciated.
- Am I correctly handling errors?

---

```
import os
import re
import shutil


def command_new_project(project_name: str, project_description: str):
    """Generate a new project.

    This function generates a new project. A
    project structure looks like this:

        /[project name]
            /source
                ...

            /versions
                ...

            /info
                readme.txt
                changelog.txt

    Keyword arguments:
    project_name        -- The name of the project.
    project_description -- A brief description of the project.
    """
    os.makedirs("./{0}".format(project_name))
    os.chdir("./{0}".format(project_name))

    os.makedirs("./source")
    os.makedirs("./versions")
    os.makedirs("./info")

    with \
        open("./info/readme.txt", "w+") as readme, \
        open("./info/changelog.txt", "w+") as changelog:
        readme.write(project_description)


def command_push_version(version_number: str, version_description: str):
    """Push a new version.

    This function pushes a the contents of the
    ./[project name]/source folder to a new folder
    in ./[project name]/versions named with the
    version number.

    Keyword arguments:
    version_number      -- The version number. Must contain valid characters for folder names.
    version_description -- A brief description of the changes in the version to be written to the changelog.
    """
    if re.match("[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\s\.]+", version_number):
        with open("./info/changelog.txt", "w") as changelog:
            shutil.make_archive("./versions/{0}".format(version_number), format="zip", root_dir="./source")
            changelog.write("\nVersion {0}".format(version_number))
            changelog.write(version_description)


def command_change_directory(directory: str):
    """Change to a new directory.

    This function allows the user to navigate to
    another directory.

    Keyword arguments:
    directory -- The directory to navigate to.
    """
    try:
        os.chdir(directory)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass


def validate_user_input(valid_command, valid_arguments_length, command, arguments):
    """Validate user input.

    This function checks to make sure that the
    format that a user enters a command in is
    correct.

    Keyword arguments:
    valid_command          -- The valid command to check against.
    valid_arguments_length -- The valid length of the list of inputted arguments.
    command                -- The command.
    arguments              -- The arguments of the command.
    """
    if len(arguments) == valid_arguments_length:
        if command == valid_command:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


def execute_user_input(tokenized_user_input: list):
    """Execute tokenized user input.

    This function executes user input, like the
    command "new::Awesome Project::A really awesome project."
    after it's been tokenized.

    Keyword arguments:
    tokenized_user_input -- The tokenized form of the user's input.
    """
    command = tokenized_user_input[0]
    arguments = tokenized_user_input[1:]

    if validate_user_input("new", 2, command, arguments):
        command_new_project(arguments[0], arguments[1])

    if validate_user_input("push", 2, command, arguments):
        command_push_version(arguments[0], arguments[1])

    if validate_user_input("changedir", 1, command, [arguments]):
        command_change_directory(arguments[0])


def tokenize_user_input(user_input):
    """Tokenize user input into a list.

    This function tokenizes the user's input into a
    form that the execute_user_input function can
    correctly interpret.

    Keyword arguments:
    user_input -- The user's input.
    """
    tokenized_user_input = re.split("\s*::\s*", user_input)
    return tokenized_user_input


def main():
    while True:
        user_input = input("lsc> ")
        execute_user_input(tokenize_user_input(user_input))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you're curious about this project, you can find it on Github, [here](https://github.com/ShearOfDoom/LSC).

Comment: `<CommentReview>` Pretty cool, but sorely missing a way to get a version back into the working directory. `<CommentReview />`

Comment: @RubberDuck Feel free to open an issue on the repo! :)

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/98785/9357)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, the error handling needs work: you are swallowing `FileNotFoundError`, discarding invalid input, and generally ignoring all kinds of failures.  (In my experience, adding good error handling easily doubles the programming effort required.)  There is no `quit` or `exit` command, nor do you handle `EOFError` gracefully.

`::` isn't exactly the most user-friendly token separator.

The docstrings are too verbose for my personal taste, and get in the way of the code.

The command dispatch mechanism could be smarter.  To add a new command, you have to define a function *and* add a condition to `execute_user_input()`.  Furthermore, you need to specify the number of expected arguments, repeating yourself.  The linear search for a matching command is also inelegant by Python standards.

The solution for all of that, I believe, [introspection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).  I've also used variable-length argument lists for clarity and to avoid the awkward `command = tokenized_user_input[0]; arguments = tokenized_user_input[1:]` assignments.

```
import inspect
import os
import re
import shutil

class Commands:
    @staticmethod
    def new(project_name, project_description):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def push(version_number, version_description):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def changedir(directory):
        """Change to a new directory."""
        try:
            os.chdir(directory)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass    # TODO: error handling


def execute_user_input(command, *arguments):
    """
    Execute command, if the command exists and the correct number of arguments
    have been given.
    """
    function = getattr(Commands, command, None)
    if function is None or command.startswith('_'):
        return  # TODO: error handling
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(function)
    if ( len(arguments) == len(argspec.args) or
         len(arguments) > len(argspec.args) and argspec.varargs ):
        function(*arguments)

def tokenize_user_input(user_input):
    """Tokenize user input into a list."""
    return re.split("\s*::\s*", user_input)


def main():
    while True:
        user_input = input("lsc> ")
        execute_user_input(*tokenize_user_input(user_input))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```